# Android ProGuard: Keeping Inner Annotated Interface

Tags: android, annotations, proguard, inner-classes, android-proguard

I have a class:

```
public class Cars {

    @IntDef(flag = true, value = {Condition.NEW, Condition.USED})
    @interface Condition {
         int NEW = 0, int USED = 1
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find a a proguard rule that will allow the Condition class not to be obfuscated.

I've tried multiple variations of:

```
-keep @interface com.vungle.warren.downloader.DownloadRequest.Status
```

but still receive the error when compiling:

```
can't find referenced class com.testapp.app.models.Car$Condition
```

Does anything have an idea on what proguard rule would cover this scenario?